# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, pyinstaller, theano

I was trying to convert my python code to an executable using pyinstaller. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with pyinstaller=3.5 and setuptools=41.2.0. When i run the executable, I'm getting the following error:

```
Using Theano backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main_test.py", line 25, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "code.py", line 2, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/keras/backend/load_backend.py", line 87, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 7, in <module>
File "/home/g2-test/anaconda3/envs/ashna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 247, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams'
[6919] Failed to execute script main_test
```

I used

> pyinstaller --onefile main_test.py

to generate the executable. I had used keras but while running the executable, it is showing using theano backend.
Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate the following:

```
- your.code.files.py
- hooks
  - hook-theano.py
```

And in `hook-theano.py`:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('theano')
```

Then build with the extra option, `--addtional-hooks-dir=hooks`.

If you encounter other issues with more module not found errors, (let's say you can't find `mymod.pkg.func`), create a new file under `hooks`, called `hook-mymod.py`.

Comment: Should i run this as: pyinstaller --onefile \ ----addtional-hooks-dir=hooks\ code.files.py ?

Comment: `pyinstaller --onefile --additional-hook-dir=hooks yourscript.py` should work

Answer (score -2):

1. Open terminal
2. Type `sudo pip3 install theano`

If it doesn't recognize the command `pip3`, then check if pip is installed by doing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378349/when-using-sudo-to-run-pip-pip-command-not-found-but-its-installed), assuming it is installed. If it isn't type `sudo apt-get install pip3`

Comment: I tried uninstalling and installing theano with this command. The installation was successful. But, still I'm getting the same error.